# Snowflake Joining 2 table doesn't load both table at once

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Running a query like:

```
select *
from (select * from tableA where date = '2020-07-01') as prev

join 

(select * from tableB where di_data_dt = '2020-08-01') as cur

on prev.ID = cur.ID;
```

**Query Profile shows:**
[image]

**Question:**
Why is snowflake loading the first table and then second table and then join? Why can't it load both together and save time?

P.S: I am using an XL warehouse and table is not super massive that snowflake can't handle tohether.

Comment: _loading the first table and then second table and then join_ what makes you think that? Why do you think the tables aren't being loaded in parallel? Do you have an actual performance issue?

Comment: I am saying that because it loads table 1 fist (all records), then loads table 2 (all records) and then join. This screenshot was taken while the job was running. After the left table was loaded, it started loading the right side table and then join....it is a performance issue because it takes 45 minutes (doing this approach), if it was to load both tables in parallel, it will save atleast 50% of the time

Comment: Hi user2221179, I am not sure if it will improve the query because i am not able to see all the metrics in the the query profile. But can you please try this

1. Create two temporary table as below

CREATE TEMP TABLE PREV AS SELECT * FROM TABLEA where date = '2020-07-01' ORDER BY ID;
CREATE TEMP TABLE PREV AS SELECT * FROM TABLEB where di_data_dt = '2020-08-01' ORDER BY ID;

2. Now join PREV AND CUR

SELECT * FROM PREV JOIN CUR ON PREV.ID = CUR.ID;

Comment: This has nothing to do with what Snowflake can "handle".  If you notice in the profile that there is a join filter step in there.  Snowflake will attempt to not "load" the entire second table, if it finds ability to prune (filter) that table and minimize what it needs to load.  If Snowflake were to load both tables at the same time, you'd lose out on that filtering in queries that allow for it.  As an additional note, why are you using sub-selects in your JOIN?  That's not exactly optimal SQL.

Comment: @RajibDeb: it will mean the same thing as what snowflake is doing right now.

Comment: @MikeWalton: it's part of a use case according to which I have to do sub-select in the join. That being said, if you look at the query, Snowflake will load this table twice anyways because it needs to scan two different date filter. I am just saying why can't it do it in parallel?

Comment: @user2221179 Snowflake uses the size of your warehouse to do each scan, anyway, so I'm not sure what the concern is.  Not sure I understand your comment on scanning the same table twice, either.  That doesn't happen.  And again, if Snowflake uses the full power of the warehouse to scan each table sequentially, it'll just scan the first one faster, right?  Now, it has the information it needs to know what will need to be scanned in the second table.  Snowflake is very efficient in this regard.

Comment: @MikeWalton: Its hard to explain the concern here because I can't share details of the use case and what I am seeing in Query Profile. I will work with the Snowflake Account Manager assigned to our organization to take this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake clusters utilize all the available bandwidth for remote IO and transfer is already distributed across the cluster.  If one table can be retrieved at a rate of X, then two tables would be retrieved at a rate of approximately 0.5 * X, so would take the same total time.

@mike-walton points out that the doing the scans sequentially can result in faster queries due to the partition pruning that can result from join filters.

Snowflake makes a plan for the entire query, so if there is one step that needs Partitions A & B from Table A, and a later sub-select that needs Partitions B & C, then A, B and C would be retrieved during one tablescan.

Comment: Thanks Nat, your explanation makes lot of sense. Probably Mike was also trying to point of the same thing, but your reference make it more easy to grasp.